# Inherit python object in Django model

Tags: python, django, inheritance, django-models, django-inheritance

I'm trying to understand, if it is possible to inherit a regular python class in a `django` model. The idea is that I need a common interface for the models and for another part of the system(that works with mongo).

The example is:

```
class myC(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self.f = "test"

class myM(myC, models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Making `myC` inherit from Model and making it abstract is not really possible for me and even more. So I wonder, what would the table for `myM` look like(if what I am trying to do is possible).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could inherit your models from regular classes. For example create some mixins for your models.
This mixin will add missing `/` to `url` field each time you save a model:

```
class ModelURLSaveMixin(object):

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.url.startswith('/'):
           self.url = '/' + self.url
        if not self.url.endswith('/'):
            self.url = self.url + '/'
        super(ModelURLSaveMixin, self).save(*args, **kwargs)


 class MyModelWithUrlField(ModelURLSaveMixin, models.Model):
     ...
```

But if you want build common interface for several models on your project an abstract class solution will be better